# Debian and Kernel Versions

Tags: debian, kernel

Debian is running 2.6.32-5.  Recent kernels seem to have addressed some kernel soft lockup issues, I'd like to try them.  Although... the patches don't *seem* to be in the Debian-stable repository.

```
# dpkg -l linux-image-2.6.32-5-686
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version                Description
+++-======================-==================================================================================
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-5-6 2.6.32-44              Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs
```

- Why is the Debian "Version" 2.6.32-44 when the kernel is 2.6.32-5 ?
- What does upgrading to Debian version 2.6.32-45 (of the 2.6.32-5 kernel) buy me?  I can't seem to find the Debian release notes on this upgrade/fix/patch.
- I assume Debian isn't backporting Kernel patches.  Can I just download the latest deb of the kernel, modules and dependencies and dpkg -i it?  Sure I won't be on a "stable" kernel, but at least my system might not be doing the soft-lockups.

Any help would be appreciated.  Pointers to specific Debian documentation on this would be ideal.  There's something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the Debian "Version" 2.6.32-44 when the kernel is 2.6.32-5?

Because that is how Debian names their packages.

> I assume Debian isn't backporting Kernel patches.

Debian backports any patches for **security** issues.  It does not add new features, or update to resolve issues only seen by a small number of people.  I like the definition of [stable here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/post/120566/#p120566).

> Can I just download the latest deb of the kernel

Enable the backports repository.  You will get access to a many new kernels, just keep in mind that the backports repository doesn't receive the same level of coverage by the security team.

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

The latest packaged kernel in the backports repository seems to be `linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.2`.